# Using LightGBM in CPU and GPU modes

Tags: gpu, lightgbm

I'm currently using LightGBM in CPU mode and want to try it in GPU mode. The flags for CPU and GPU modes are different. What are the options so that I can switch between the CPU and the GPU modes? Is using conda env the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs here https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html?highlight=gpu#run-your-first-learning-task-on-gpu and also on the GitHub page: https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Installation-Guide.rst